# Overriding save method of User model with Abstract user in django

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-rest-framework-jwt

Django project with multiple two user types. I followed this [tutorial](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/01/18/how-to-implement-multiple-user-types-with-django.html) to give two types of flags to the built in User model. When I try to login to django rest_framework_simple_jwt's login endpoint the response. Is there a problem in overriding save method.

> {
>       "non_field_errors": [
>           "No active account found with the given credentials"
>       ] }

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    email = models.EmailField(unique=False,)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_employee=models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_manager=models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def save(self,*args,**kwargs):
        if self.is_employee:
                Employee.objects.create(manager=self)
        super(User,self).save(*args,**kwargs)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that your `User` isn't created when you're trying to create the `Employee` object. One approach could be to use the [`post_save`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/instances/#what-happens-when-you-save) signal like this:

```
from django.db import models
from django.dispatch import receiver

class User(AbstractUser):
    email = models.EmailField(unique=False,)        
    # ...other fields
    # and don't override save()

@receiver(models.signals.post_save, sender=User)
def user_created(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created and instance.is_employee:
        Employee.objects.create(manager=instance)
```

Basically, we want to create an `Employee` only after the user is saved (and has a `pk`) in the database.

More references: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/signals/#post-save

Comment: I tried it in the shell. Employee object isn't being created (not going in the loop). Neither does the created user get login access at the django rest framework simplejwt endpoint. Are we not doing some kind of verification like unique username or something of that sort that grants users access.